# Switching between Active Directory Auth and Windows Auth

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, forms-authentication

G'day Guys,

I have encountered a bit of an issue where I have developed a web application that acts as an intranet and Authenticates from active directory. For the purposes of development I need to authenticate on my local machine as I don't have access to the AD DCs until I physically take the project on to thew internal network.

I have used the following resource to build the Auth module https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649227.aspx and now I am just wondering how I could implement some thing like below to switch between windows auth and AD based on if I am working in debug but still use my login form, in essence something to switch the auth context from domain to machine:

```html
#if DEBUG
            // authenticates against your local machine - for development time
            ContextType authenticationType = ContextType.Machine;
#else
            // authenticates against your Domain AD
            ContextType authenticationType = ContextType.Domain;
#endif
```

Comment: That article is only useful when the IIS machine hosting this ASP.NET application is not part of the domain. Simply use IIS/ASP.NET built-in Windows authentication, which works both for local machine (for development) and AD (once deploy to a domain machine).